# marginal pdfs of simple random samples with replacement

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

If a questions asks us to take a random sample of three observations from a population, where each observation in the sample is chosen by a random draw from the entire population and we have to find marginal pdfs of $X_1, X_2, X_3$, wouldn't that be redundant since $X_1, X_2, X_3$ would be the same?

I am confused as to how $X_1, X_2, X_3$ would different from each other. I'm not sure if I am misunderstanding the concept as a whole/doing it wrong, or the professor just wanted us to take the same marginal pdfs multiple times... Could someone walk me through this?

Comment: I think it depends on what the definitions of $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ are.

Comment: @callculus if the population is of size 8, and R is 26, 26, 26, 38, 38, 38, 96, 96. Wouldn't $X_1, X_2, X_3$ just be 26, 38, 96, hence the same?

Comment: I think what callculus is meaning is that you haven't defined $X_1$, $X_2$ or $X_3$, and also haven't $R$.

Comment: @SamT I don't think I'm understanding how to do it then. With given information of population size and R, how would I calculate $X_1, X_2, X3$?

Comment: What is $X_1$? $R$?

Comment: @qhand Usually the random variables are defined. For instance $X_1$: Number of 26 if you draw three times a ball from 5 balls numbered as $26, 26, 26, 38, 38, 38, 96, 96$ without repetition. Many other definitions are thinkable. All in all, it depends on the definition of the random variables.